Combine text embeddings
What's the best way to combine text embeddings into one and then search in vector db?
I'm trying to create a recommendation  system, so when a user clicks on another category, I get the text embedding and I add it to the "combined embedding".
For example, If a user clicks on food recipes, the user's feed should have more results about food recipes and less for sports or work.
I use the following formula: vector1 + vector2 + vector3 + ... = [(a1+b1+c1),(a2+b2+c2) ...]. but the results are not great.

Combining text embeddings into a single vector and then searching in a vector database is a common task in various natural language processing (NLP) applications such as semantic search, document retrieval, and recommendation systems. Here's a general approach:
Vector Representation: First, you need to represent each text document or input as a vector. This is typically done using pre-trained word embeddings like Word2Vec, GloVe, or FastText, or more sophisticated methods like BERT embeddings.
Aggregation: Once you have word embeddings for each word in your text, you need to aggregate them into a single vector representation for the entire document. There are several techniques you can use for aggregation:
Averaging: Simply average all word embeddings in the document.
Summation: Sum up all word embeddings.
Weighted Average: Weight the word embeddings based on TF-IDF scores or other relevance scores.
Pooling: Apply max-pooling or mean-pooling across word embeddings.
Doc2Vec/Paragraph Vectors: Train a model to generate document-level embeddings directly.
Vector Database: Once you have the aggregated embeddings for all documents, you can index them in a vector database. Popular choices include:
FAISS: A high-performance similarity search library that supports both CPU and GPU.
Annoy: Another efficient library for approximate nearest neighbor search.
Elasticsearch with Vector Plugin: If you're using Elasticsearch, you can use plugins like the Vector Plugin to perform similarity search on vector embeddings.
Search: When you want to search for similar documents, you compute the embedding of the query text using the same process used for documents, and then perform a similarity search in the vector database. This will return the most similar documents based on their vector representations.
